# ASP.Net route not being hit, returning 404 error on postman?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Web API router that seems to not get hit when I navigate to the proper route.

Here is my Web API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    #region Declarations
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    #endregion

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        ApplicationDbContext context,
        IHostingEnvironment environment
        )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _context = context;
        _hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "Account", "Controller" };
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken()
    {
        var client = new DiscoveryClient("http://localhost:15547");
        client.Policy.RequireHttps = false;
        var disco = await client.GetAsync();
        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            return BadRequest(disco.Error);
        }

        TokenClient tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "ro.angular", "secret");
        TokenResponse tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("ahmer", "Default@69", "api1 openid");

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            return BadRequest(tokenResponse.Error);
        }

        //var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

        var result = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("ahmer");

        return BadRequest("Invalid username or password.");
    }
}
```

However, my GET `http://localhost:15547/api/account/` route works fine, but when I try to make a POST request `http://localhost:15547/api/account/GetToken` it is not hit and it shows me 404 message from Postman. What I m doing wrong in my code.

**Output 1**

[image]

**Output 2**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET CORE default route is different than ASP.NET MVC default route system.

Right now :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken()
```

will match to `POST : http://localhost:15547/api/account` even if action name is `GetToken`. So that's why you hit 404.

You must set the route template to "gettoken" to make it work as you want:

```
[HttpPost("gettoken")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken()
```

This will instruct ASP.NET that this action should match to `POST http://localhost:15547/api/account/GetToken`

Comment: To clarify, this occurs because of the use of attribute routing (specifically using `Route` on the controller level, which results in a switch to the type of routing). Once you're using attribute routing, it's all the way. Any actions without explicit routes are assigned an empty route, i.e. `api/account`, since that is the prefix that's defined.